# Adding extra parameters to Auth Provider URLs

Tags: authentication, oauth, auth-provider

Is it possible to add extra parameters to the auto generated SF URLs in Auth. Provider?

To be more clear, here's an example:
We have an Auth. Provider with an auto generated URL(let's say https://mysandbox.cs128.force.com/mycommunity/services/auth/sso/test), which then redirects me to

> https://somesuthprovider.com/clientsecret-oidc/csapi/v0.1/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=abcdef&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysandbox.cs128.force.com%2Fmycommunity%2Fservices%2Fauthcallback%2Ftest&scope=openid+service%3AMY_LOGIN+profile+email+phone+address&state=some_long_state_string

What I want is to add an extra parameter to that URL at the end: claims={"userinfo":{"param1":null,"param2":null,"param3":null}}, so that the URL looks like this:

> https://somesuthprovider.com/clientsecret-oidc/csapi/v0.1/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=abcdef&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysandbox.cs128.force.com%2Fmycommunity%2Fservices%2Fauthcallback%2Ftest&scope=openid+service%3AMY_LOGIN+profile+email+phone+address&state=some_long_state_string&claims={"userinfo":{"param1":null,"param2":null,"param3":null}}

I tried adding it to the Authorize Endpoint URL in a hope that this will work, but I only got the error saying

> Error: Specify a valid URL starting with http:// or https://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to encode those curley brackets and quotes. They're not listed in the characters that should not be encoded.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577922/how-to-pass-a-json-array-as-a-parameter-in-url